# Obtaining FontMetrics before getting a Graphics instance

Tags: java, fontmetrics

Typically, I'd obtain a graphics instance something like this:

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
```

However, in the current project I'm working on, the `width` and `height` variables above are dependent upon the size of a number of text fragments that will later be drawn onto the graphics instance. But, to obtain the dimensions of the font being used I would usually use the FontMetrics that I get from the graphics object.

```
FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics();
```

So, I have a nasty little dependency cycle. I cannot create the graphics object until I know the size of the text, and I cannot know the size of the text until I have a graphics object. One solution is just to create another `BufferedImage`/`Graphics` pair first in order to get the `FontMetrics` instance I need, but this seems unnecessary.

- So, is there a nicer way?
- Or is it the case that the width, height etc. properties for a Font are somehow dependent upon what (graphics, component...) the text is to be drawn on?

Comment: I got the pretty much the same problem here Tom, did you ever find a nice solution tho this?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. I just resorted to creating a temporary Graphics object. I'd be interested to hear if you find a better way though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to get a Graphics instance from some other place. For example, the panel on which the image will be painted on. Then you can get a FontMetrics instance using that Graphic instance.